# Dissection of strange graph

Tags: graphing-functions

I want to know why the graph in [Strange graph problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783065/strange-graph-problem) looks how it does. Can someone explain? Here's the inequality:

$(|x|−1)^2+(|y|−1)^2<2$

You can graph this equation at https://www.desmos.com/calculator. Make sure to change the $<$ to $=$.

Comment: See @Jared's answer to your previous question.  Basically, find the part of the graph in the first quadrant by taking $x,y\ge0$ so that you get the familiar equation $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=2$.  Then copy this bit symmetrically in every other quadrant.

Comment: Why is it copied symmetrically, though? What part of the equation does that?

Comment: In Quadrant I, $|x| = x$, $|y| = y$. In Quadrant II, $|x| = -x$, $|y|=y$. Etc...

Comment: post it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very often, people get intimidated by the absolute value sign (myself included), but it's really simple if you break it apart.

In Quadrant I: $x,y\ge0$, so $|x| = x$ and $|y| = y$.
In Quadrant II: $x\le0$, $y\ge0$, so $|x| = -x$ and $|y| = y$, etc.

By removing the absolute values in this way, one obtains equations of circles in the appropriate quadrants.